# Build failure when using some String.IndexOf overrides

Tags: c#, .net

When I try to use `String.IndexOf(string value, StringComparer comparisonType)`, I get a build failure. This seems like an environment issue, but I tried reinstalling Visual Studio and it still fails. I am using .NET 4.5.2, and Intellisense is giving me the option of `String.IndexOf(string value, StringComparer comparisonType)`

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string test = "TEST";
            string test2 = "t";
            test.IndexOf(test2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // Causes build failure.
        }
    }
}
```

I get the build errors:

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.StringComparer' to 'int'

It is clearly trying to use the `String.IndexOf(char value, int startIndex)` function.

I tested this on .NET Fiddle and it works, so right now I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.5.2), IndexOf uses the `StringComparison` enum, while you are using the `StringComparer` object. Try switching to `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: I KNEW I was doing something stupid and depending on Intellisense too much. StringComparer was the first in the list, and I didn't even think about it.

siiiiiiiiiiiigh

Answer (score 0):

StringComparer is an abstract class. Replace it with StringComparison, and cast that to int:

```
test.IndexOf(test2, (int)StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

That way the code should compile.

Comment: Your code _does_ compile if I select .NET Framework 4.7.2, which happens to be the .NET Framework dotnetfiddle uses.